# Android Studio Layout designer doesn't work after update

Tags: android, android-studio

I have project that perfectly worked before installing/updating Android Studio 3.3. Today I had to change something in my Android app and Layout Designer doesn't work properly any more. It means that doesn't show Widgets like buttons, textviews and other stuffs in design time. Also I can't add nothing on layout using drag and drop. 
When I create a new project with Empty activity it works fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: have you update your gradle as well ?

Comment: Everything is updated.
Few minutes ago I just added new blank activity to this project and then I put some widgets and suddenly everything showed.  Why? I don't know. Seems that each time with new update of IDE comes new bugs... Google should be more careful before releasing new versions.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is with Gradle, go to `build.gradle` then change your versions to these these:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

if it didn't fixed your problem, tell me

Comment: downgrading your gradle version fixed it?